# Rails 3. How can I only display one nested model form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have these two models: Company and CompanyContact.

So I have the usual...

```
companies_controller.rb
def edit
  @company = Company.find(params[:id])
  student = @company.students.build
  company_contact = @company.company_contacts.build
end

company.rb
has_many :company_contacts, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_contacts, :reject_if => :reject_company_contacts, :allow_destroy => true

company_contact.rb
belongs_to :company

form.html.erb
<%= f.fields_for :company_contacts do |builder| %>
  <%= render "company_contact_fields", :f => builder %>
<% end %>

_company_contacts.html.erb
<p style="margin:5px 0;">
  <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, :class => 'text_field' %>
</p>

<p style="margin:5px 0;">
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :email, :class => 'text_field' %>
</p>
```

In the edit form, if I already have a company contact for a company, it gives me that existing record plus another empty company contact form ready to be filled out. Which is ok because that it's supposed to happen.

What I need to do is only have ONE company contact, so if there is already a company contact, I don't want to display another form to add an extra company contact. I do not want to setup a has_one relationship because my client might want to add extra company contacts in the future and also when I tried a has_one relationship I got bunch of errors.

Ok so to only have ONE company contact per company, I tried a counter solution, you know in the loop set counter = 0 and then check if counter > 0 but that "solution" didn't work. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correct, then

```
@company.company_contacts.build unless @company.company_contacts.present?
```

is what you are looking for.

This way, if a company already has a contact, then no more contacts are built. Likewise, if a company has no contact, this will build up contacts which shall then be used by `f.fields_for :company_contacts` to render in the form.